# Error trying to compile netty from the master branch

Tags: netty

I did git clone git://github.com/netty/netty.git

then

mvn install -Dcheckstyle.skip

The -Dcheckstyle.skip is because previous errors related to the style checking.

Now I am getting compilations errors on the buffer module,

Note: I am using JDK 1.7 (Mac OSX 64bits version downloaded and installed from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u4-downloads-1591156.html ) and maven 3.0.4

The console output:

[INFO] Building Netty/Buffer 4.0.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

...

[INFO] Compiling 23 source files to /Users/jars/workspace/rhyboo-sources/netty/buffer/target/classes

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
/Users/jars/workspace/rhyboo-sources/netty/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/array/ObjectArray.java:[4,36] error: cannot find symbol

[ERROR]  class AbstractArray
/Users/jars/workspace/rhyboo-sources/netty/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/array/ObjectArray.java:[12,21] error: cannot find symbol

[ERROR] 
    E extends Object declared in class ObjectArray
/Users/jars/workspace/rhyboo-sources/netty/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/array/ObjectArray.java:[10,4] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Is there documentation related to compile and run netty examples?, or then import the project on eclipse?

Thanks in advance, netty looks an amazing nio client server framework.

Answer (score 0):

One of the leaders of the Netty project (probably Trustin) forgot to upload the AbstractArray class. I will let him know, so it should hopefully be fixed soon.

I don't know what he had written for it, otherwise I would make it myself and use a pull request. At the moment, I'm working on fixing all of the checkstyle audit errors.

Good luck with Netty! I'll let you know once it's fixed - There was a big API change, so a few things broke.

P.S.: If you don't want the latest changes, you can always switch to one of the 'tags' - I think you just check them out the same way as the regular branches.

~Cruz

Answer (score 0):

We are currently under heavy refactoring going on at master and the build is broken.  It should be fixed by the end of this week, but for now, please use the branch '3'.